# Going Back to Previous Screens

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and I'm trying to figure out how to go back to a previous screen/activity after opening another screen using startActivity.  From all the research I've done, using the finish() method should bring up the previous screen just before the current one; however, in my test program (has four screens with a "next" & "back"button), when pressing the back button, it jumps all the way back to the first screen instead of going to the previous screen.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private Button next;
    private Button quit;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

     next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit);

        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        quit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

      switch(view.getId()) {  

        case R.id.next: {
             startActivity(new Intent(this, Screen2.class));
        }
        case R.id.quit: {

             finish();
        }

      }

     }

 }




public class Screen2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private Button next;
    private Button back;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

     next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

      switch(view.getId()) {  

        case R.id.next: {
             startActivity(new Intent(this, Screen3.class));
        }
        case R.id.back: {

             finish();
        }

      }

     }

 }





public class Screen3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private Button next;
    private Button back;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.screen3);

     next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

      switch(view.getId()) {  

        case R.id.next: {
             startActivity(new Intent(this, Screen4.class));
        }
        case R.id.back: {

             finish();
        }

      }

     }

 }




public class Screen4 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



    private Button back;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.screen4);

        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

             finish();
        }


     }

 }
```

Comment: The 'back' button on Android devices do this kind of behavior for you by default. Is there any reason you need an explicit back button in your application? Chances are that you do NOT need it.

Comment: No, I really do not need it, just thought it would be nice to have it there in addition to the back button on the device.  However, the same behavior occurs with the back button on the device.  Is there a possibility that the activities are not being saved on the stack?  I'm using Eclipse Helios v. 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

The Recorder Activity demo in the official API Demo might be of help.

Here are the links to their source code.

[Recorder Activity One (Launcher)](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ReorderOnLaunch.html)

[Recorder Activity Two](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ReorderTwo.html)

[Recorder Activity Three](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ReorderThree.html)

[Recorder Activity Four (This is where it gets interesting)](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ReorderFour.html)